# entity framework adding data it shouldnt through other object

Tags: mysql, vb.net, entity-framework, database-design

I think this question has been asked already, i just can't seem to find an answer i understand.
I have a program that works with entity framework - code first.

When the program runs and the database is not created yet, it will create it and add some data to it as well.
The data it adds are 3 categories, each customer will get a category assigned when a object of customer is created.
The 3 categories are also databound to a combobox, when a customer is created, the categorie is selected from the combobox

problem: when a customer is created, a copy of the category seems to be created as well, the category copy is added to the table of categories (not suppose to happen in my head) and then of course this copy is also added to the combobox.

I'm having trouble understanding why this is happening and what i did wrong.
I'm also not sure which parts of the code i should post here or where i should be looking for error, although i have a feeling the situation result from a bad database design/class design.
This is my first time working with entity framework

**Code for the databindings**

```
            Dim DisplayLimos As New BindingSource
            context.LimosDb.Load()
            DisplayLimos.DataSource = context.LimosDb.Local.ToBindingList()
            CbLimos.DataSource = DisplayLimos
            CbLimos.DisplayMember = "Info"
            Dim DisplayCategories As New BindingSource
            context.CategoriesDb.Load()
            DisplayCategories.DataSource = context.CategoriesDb.Local.ToBindingList()
            CbCategorie.DataSource = DisplayCategories
            CbCategorie.DisplayMember = "Naam"
            Dim DisplayKlanten As New BindingSource
            context.KlantenDb.Load()
            DisplayKlanten.DataSource = context.KlantenDb.Local.ToBindingList()
            ListBoxKlanten.DataSource = DisplayKlanten
            ListBoxKlanten.DisplayMember = "Naam"
            Dim displayArrangementen As New BindingSource
            context.ArrangementenDb.Load()
            displayArrangementen.DataSource = context.ArrangementenDb.Local.ToBindingList()
            CbArrangementen.DataSource = displayArrangementen
            CbArrangementen.DisplayMember = "Naam"
```

**Code for populating the categories table** the second parameter is a class that holds discounts for each category

```
        Dim categorieVip As New KlantenCategorie("Vip", kortingVip)
        Dim categorieWedding As New KlantenCategorie("Wedding", kortingWeddingPlanner)
        Dim categorieNightLife As New KlantenCategorie("NightLife", kortingConcertenPlanner)
        context.CategoriesDb.Add(categorieVip)
        context.CategoriesDb.Add(categorieWedding)
        context.CategoriesDb.Add(categorieNightLife)
        context.SaveChanges()
```

**Code that adds the customer to the database and where the error occurs that a copy of the category is also created**

```
Private Sub BtnKlant_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnKlant.Click
    Dim adres As New Adres(TxbStraat.Text, TxbHuisN.Text, CType(TxbPostCode.Text, Integer), TxbGemeente.Text)
    Dim klant As New Klant(CType(TxbKlantNr.Text, Integer), TxbVoorNaam.Text, TxbNaam.Text, adres, CType(TxbBtwNr.Text, Integer), CType(CbCategorie.SelectedValue, KlantenCategorie))
    Try
        _Context.KlantenDb.Add(klant)
        _Context.SaveChanges()
        ListBoxKlanten.Refresh()
        MessageBox.Show("Klant succesvol toegevoegt")
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe i have found where my mistake lies.

In the part where i create a new customer and pass through the category it should have

```
Private Sub BtnKlant_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnKlant.Click
    Dim adres As New Adres(TxbStraat.Text, TxbHuisN.Text, CType(TxbPostCode.Text, Integer), TxbGemeente.Text)
    Dim klant As New Klant(CType(TxbKlantNr.Text, Integer), TxbVoorNaam.Text, TxbNaam.Text, adres, CType(TxbBtwNr.Text, Integer), CType(CbCategorie.SelectedValue, KlantenCategorie))
    Try
        _Context.KlantenDb.Add(klant)
        _Context.SaveChanges()
        ListBoxKlanten.Refresh()
        MessageBox.Show("Klant succesvol toegevoegt")
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try


End Sub
```

I changed this

```
Dim klant As New Klant(CType(TxbKlantNr.Text, Integer), TxbVoorNaam.Text, TxbNaam.Text, adres, CType(TxbBtwNr.Text, Integer), CType(CbCategorie.SelectedValue, KlantenCategorie))
```

to this

```
 Dim klant As New Klant(CType(TxbKlantNr.Text, Integer), TxbVoorNaam.Text, TxbNaam.Text, adres, CType(TxbBtwNr.Text, Integer), _Context.CategoriesDb.First(Function(ct) ct.Naam = CbCategorie.Text))
```

Using a lambda to pull the correct category out of the database and link it to the new customer created. (atleast that is how i understand it)

This link is what i am mostly going on to create this project, one of the few i found on code first EF with actual VB examples.
http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2012/03/07/an-ef-code-first-tutorial.aspx

If anyone wants to add criticism to my way of working or coding, please do!
I am always open to improving my nooby skills :)